# Android Studio JNI with C++ UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using Android Studio 2.1.2 I am not using Experimental Plugin

Please Check the following files and Check the error I am getting.

I solved the issue. Edited file is as follows. They way I fixed it may not be the correct way as I am setting property to use deprecated way, but it works. Experimental plugin can still be unstable. I will try with experimental plugin soon.

build.gradle from Module

```
sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        /*jni.srcDirs = [] not using this, I commented this. Please check SO links which explained when to use this and when not to use this*/
    }
```

following 4 files are in jni folder of main

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJni.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := all
```

HelloJni.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <Header.h>

 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_m1035325_ndksampleapp_MainActivity_getStringFromJni(JNIEnv *env,jobject thiz)
 {
 env-> NewStringUTF ( "Hellofrom JNI!");
 }
```

Header.h

```
#include <jni.h>;
using namespace std;

#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_m1035325_ndksampleapp_MainActivity_getStringFromJni(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
}

#endif //NDKSAMPLEAPP_HEADER_H
```

MainActicity.java

```
static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("mylib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tvHello=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
        tvHello.setText(getStringFromJni());
    }

    public native String getStringFromJni();
```

Here when I hover on method getStringFromJni it shows Can't resolve corresponding JNI function

I have set NDK path in Project Structure and in Path environment variable too.

I am getting following error

```
Process: com.example.m1035325.ndksampleapp, PID: 12831
                                                                                   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.example.m1035325.ndksampleapp.MainActivity.getStringFromJni() (tried Java_com_example_m1035325_ndksampleapp_MainActivity_getStringFromJni and Java_com_example_m1035325_ndksampleapp_MainActivity_getStringFromJni__)
                                                                                       at com.example.m1035325.ndksampleapp.MainActivity.getStringFromJni(Native Method)
```

I searched a lot on SO also but I am not getting what I missed?

No error now , above error is fixed. Please check my answer to this question.

Comment: You are missing `JNICALL`, the signature should start with `JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL`,

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Yes you are correct. I added it in my file. Please check my edited files above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important change I made is in file gradle.properties, is as follows

android.useDeprecatedNdk=true

so its related to Android Studio version 2.1.2 , for this version experimental plugin is the default option to use and the approach I am using is deprecated.
I will be trying with experimental plugin soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_SOURCE_FILE := HelloJni.cpp
```

AFAIK the Android build system doesn't use variable of that name. It should be:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJni.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I made this change , now on ndk-build my cpp file is compiling.Then after I fixed some errors in my CPP file, e.g NewStringUTF function call etc , did ndk-build .so generated but still on running application I am getting same "UnsatisfiedLinkError". One thing is in my MainActivity class when I hover on native method it is showing me can not resolve corresponding JNI function. Can you please help me regarding this.

Comment: Am I missing any import in MainActivity.java.. the Android UI file?